# Terraform - GCloud Container Registry Sample

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, terraform, google-container-registry

I'm working with terraforming gcloud resources and need to create gcloud container registry and trying to use below sample from terraform.io

```
data "google_container_registry_repository" {}

output "gcr_location" {
    value = "${data.google_container_registry_repository.repository_url}"
}
```

and receving below error when I run `terraform plan`

> 'data' must be followed by exactly two strings: a type and a name

Any working sample that  I can refer to ?

terraform.io syntax : https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/d/google_container_registry_repository.html

terraform version: 
Terraform v0.11.2

Edit : updated to Terraform v0.11.3 and still same problem.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the documentation.

Comment: this is a data source not a resource, gcr apparently is "weird" and has no direct api call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
data "google_container_registry_repository" "myregistry" {}

output "gcr_location" {
    value = "${data.google_container_registry_repository.myregistry.repository_url}"
}
```

Comment: receiving this now 
"Error reading config for output gcr_location: data.myregistry.repository_url: data variables must be four parts: data.TYPE.NAME.ATTR in:

${data.myregistry.repository_url"

Comment: Try with `value = "${data.google_container_registry_repository.myregistry.repository_url}"`

Answe should be updated...